# Eclipse hangs in building project after each save

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

This has become so annoying.
Each time I save an Ant build I get Eclipse in rebuilding itself...
I have Java Project which depends from a non-Java project. When I edit a file in the non-Java project, save, build. I get the whole project sync process launched... 1-5 minutes later I get the prompt back.

Comment: it also happens if I edit the java project & save & run.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to turn off automatic building globally in the Project menu. If you do this, the Build project... and Build all options become enabled, allowing you to manually build when necessary.

Another option may be to set the refresh workspace policy of your executed ANT build (granted you are using the Eclipse AntRunner): in the Run configuration on the refresh tab you could manually select only to update the project changed by the ANT build.

Comment: hum, can you help me more. What do u mean with : 'Run configuration on the refresh tab'. I'm not an expert in Eclipse, yes I run the Eclipse Ant Runner. Already turned-off the auto-build.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise, because Ant is run as an External tool. So select Run/External tools/External tools configuration, then look for your Ant task on the left, select the refresh tab on the right (with your task selected), and make sure, nothing unneeded is selected to refresh.

Comment: OK thx. Did what you said, refresh only the ressource, removed recursive refresh.... same story.

Comment: Its is a bit shorter, but every 3 edits of a file in the java project I get a resync launched.

Comment: Sorry then, I have no further idea.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, everytime I edited web.xml, it would hang showing busy icon for 5-10 seconds. I tried an older web project, and it worked fine.

I discovered that the web.xml web-app tag was different and after changing it, the problem went away. I think it has something to do with the lookup of XML schemas.

I think it is possible to disable the schema check (that goes out and download the schema every time).

But otherwise find what I changed below to make it stop hanging on every save.

From:

```
`<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">`
```

To:

```
`<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
  version="2.5">`
```

I know the version is different 2.4->2.5 but notice it references schema location differently.

Comment: I've disabled all validators and still get this problem. Is it possible to see what eclipse is up to when it hangs?

(NB. Confusingly, when I disable the validators, eclipse tells me that it need to rebuild the entire project and then says its busy validating...)